# Question on spatial join and buffer in geopandas

Tags: gis, spatial, geopandas

I have two GeoDataFrames that I am attempting to join. Both have `POINT` geometry. I am using `geopandas.buffer` to create Points and polygon and then spatial join.

`gpd1` with `POLYGON` geometry, `gpd1['geometry'] = gpd1.geometry.buffer(2)`

`gpd2` with `POINT` geometry.

Spatial Join:

```
gpd1.sjoin(gpd2, how='left')
```

Question:

What happens where there are multiple points in `gpd2` that are within the buffer / `POLYGON` geometry of `gpd1`?

Comment: you will in n points exist in polygon p, you will get n rows for polygon p

Comment: @RobRaymond is there a way to get nearest points or distance from the centroid of the `polygon`? And would the centroid of Polygon be the same as the original `POINT` geometry before creating the `buffer`?

Comment: read the docs they are good.  if you want distance as well you have the index of the point so can do a distance between the point and polygon

Comment: so you mean London is in the polygon of UK,  how far is it from the boundary?  you question is not at all specific.  maybe consider a big improvement of q

Comment: I suppose there could be some points within the polygon. In that case, how is the distance calculated?

Comment: @RobRaymond this is what I was looking for: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html ..... you can includes `distances_col` as a parameter.

Comment: I did say read the docs... !